# Omission of prepositions

Tags: grammar

I encountered the problem of understanding of preposition usage.
Here are 2 <strike>sentences</strike> noun phrases:

1. Historical sights of Rome with the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain.
   The prepositional phrase **with the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain.** refers to noun **Rome**
   That is, Rome has the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain.

If I wanted to add one more city which has  historical sights , it would be as follows:

2. Historical sights of Rome with the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain and Florence.

In the second <strike>sentence</strike> noun phrase I want to say that Rome has historical sights and Florence has historical sights.

Questions:

1. Are two <strike>sentences</strike> noun phrases correct?
2. Is there a need to add the preposition **of** before **Florence** to indicate that **Florence** refers to the noun **sights**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Semantically, it's pretty obvious you want the scope of "historical sights" to extend to "Florence", but the actual *syntax* of your construction works against that. I think this is because you've "used up" the "forward reference" scope of the initial noun ("historical sights") with the two "backward references" ("the Colosseum" and "the Trevi Fountain"). I suggest rephrasing to *Historical sights of Florence, and [**of**] Rome with the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain.* Reason for repeating ***of*** there being that it separates "Rome" better, for those who don't know where those sights are.

Comment: (1) isn't a sentence; it doesn't contain a verb. It could be the caption to a set of photographs, or a reference to a coach tour of Rome mentioning two of the places visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need *of* before Florence.  Else syntactically it could mean

> Historical sights of Rome with [the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain and Florence].

Adding a comma before the second conjunction helps to segregate Florence from the preceding attractions.  This version is possible:

> Historical sights [of Rome with the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain], and [of Florence].

However, as *of Florence* is separated too far from *Historical sights* by the long first prepositional phrase, this version is not as good as what @FumbleFingers suggested:

> Historical sights of Florence, and of Rome with the Colosseum and the Trevi Fountain.

Comment: One more question then to fully understand. Noun phrases, adjective phrases, prepositional prases always refer to the last **preposition** in the sentence, don't they? **For an example:**   **The sentence:** And its court for the trial of impeachments and correction of errors, is to consist of one branch of the legislature and the principal members of the judiciary department.  **The logic is:** **and corrections of errors** refers to **the trial** **the principal members of the judiciary department** refers to **one branch**. Do I understand it right?